# Google Calendar API 401 Login required

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I want to add a event in my calendar with php and the google-api-php-client.

The php application is the public client with some public user, and i want any user action for login to the calendar.

If i use the "simple_query" example , i can retrieve (for example) the events of my calendar.
But if i want to add a event which Requires authorization :

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert?hl=fr

a error : `401 - Login required` is call

**How i can validate authorization and add the event with any user action ?**
ex: A person navigate on the web application, add a event via a form and validate.
The php application is in charge connect to the google calendar and add the events with any interaction of the person as authentification or authorization ..

If i tried to use OAuth2, a action is ask to the public user (the person).

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "i want any user action for login to the calendar". I wouldn't *expect* any calendar to be modifiable without any sort of authorization. You might be able to use a service account instead - see https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth (expand the "learn more" part of OAuth 2.0).

Comment: Yes i'm sorry for my english...
A authorisation is required but i want it to be transparent for the person who adds the event to the application via a php form.
I try the example of the google-api-php-client but the add ask always a validation.

Comment: Then it sounds like a service account is probably what you need.

Comment: In the service account example, i must to define a p12 key, but i don't see in the api console where i can generate it...

Comment: Where did you see that you have to do that? Did you read https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount?

Comment: Yes i've read all the possibilities.

Comment: Yes i've read all the possibilities.
If i generate a new client id for my project and i specified the type service account. The p12 key is accessible.
I will try the example of the api : google-api-php-client and I come to you. Thank you

Comment: So, now it's works with the "service account" method. Thanks